# Android App started crashing after connecting to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried to create an login and registration form in android studio 3.3.1 with firebase Authentication service. So i added  firebase dependencies to the build gradle and run the app, When i click the login or register button the app crashes.

This is my build gradle code,

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.finaldemo"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    }
```

This is my Login Code,

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.finaldemo.Model.Users;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText Email,pswrd;
    private Button Login;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Email= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginemail);
        pswrd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpswrd);
        Login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loginprogressbar);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LoginUser();
            }
        });
    }
    private void LoginUser(){
        String email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        String pwd = pswrd.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            Email.setError("Email Required");
            Email.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            Email.setError("Enter a valid Email Address");
            Email.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
            pswrd.setError("Password Required");
            pswrd.requestFocus();

        }else{
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AllowAccess(email,pwd);
        }
    }

    private void AllowAccess(final String email, final String pwd) {
        final DatabaseReference Rootref;
        Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(email).exists()){

                    Users userdata = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(email).getValue(Users.class);
                    if(userdata.getEmail().equals(email)){
                        if(userdata.getPassword().equals(pwd)){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }

                }else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Account Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

This my registration Code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText fname,email,pswrd,cpswrd,phone;
    private static final Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^" + "(?=.*[0-9])" + "(?=.*[a-z])" + "(?=.*[A-Z])" + "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" + "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])" + "(?=\\S+$)" + ".{8,32}" + "$");
    //private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regfname);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regemail);
        pswrd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regpassword);
        cpswrd =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.regcpassword);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regphone);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        findViewById(R.id.regbtn).setOnClickListener(this);

       // mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.regbtn:
                createAccount();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void createAccount() {
        String name = fname.getText().toString().trim();
        String emailid = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String pwd = pswrd.getText().toString().trim();
        String cpwd = cpswrd.getText().toString().trim();
        String phoneno = phone.getText().toString().trim();

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            fname.setError("Name Required");
            fname.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (emailid.isEmpty()) {
            email.setError("Email Required");
            email.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailid).matches()) {
            email.setError("Enter a valid Email Address");
            email.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
            pswrd.setError("Password Required");
            pswrd.requestFocus();

        }
        else  if (!PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(pwd).matches()) {
            pswrd.setError("Password should contain atleast 1 upper and lowercase, 1 special char,1 number and should be between 8-32 charcters");
            pswrd.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (cpwd.isEmpty()) {
            cpswrd.setError("Password Required");
            cpswrd.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (!pwd.equals(cpwd)) {
            cpswrd.setError("Password and Confirm Password did not match");
            cpswrd.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (phoneno.isEmpty()) {
            phone.setError("Phone Number is Required");
            phone.requestFocus();

        }

        else if (phone.length() != 10) {
            phone.setError("Enter Valid Phone Number");
            phone.requestFocus();

        }
        else{
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            validateUser(name,emailid,pwd,phoneno);
        }


    }

    private void validateUser(final String name, final String emailid, final String pwd, final String phoneno) {

        final DatabaseReference Rootref;
        Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phoneno).exists() || dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(emailid).exists())){

                    HashMap<String, Object> Userdata = new HashMap<>();
                    Userdata.put("Name", name);
                    Userdata.put("Email", emailid);
                    Userdata.put("Password", pwd);
                    Userdata.put("Phone", phoneno);

                    Rootref.child("Users").child(phoneno).updateChildren(Userdata).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Congratulations, Your account has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }else{
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "The entered credentials are already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you add the stack-trace please

Comment: Logcat output is must if you want us to help you with a crash. And have you copied google-services.json file properly in app module?

Comment: I have synced firebase by tools menu in android studio, so it google-services.json file is copied automatically. How to do upload stacktrace and logcat.

Comment: Inside Android studio you'll find `logcat` tab at bottom. When app crashes you'll see stack-trace there. Copy paste that here.

Comment: Please also add the content of the other build.gradle file (Project). Have you also added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as the last line in your file? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have already applied 'com.google.gms.google-services' plugin in build.gradle file.Still its not working @AlexMamo

Comment: maybe just disconnect it? ;)

Comment: Disconnect What? @abhinav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I found out what the error is, its not in the code the error is with "com.google.gms:google-services" version in build.gradle version. Don't know why but by default it is 4.1.0, when i changed it to 4.0.1 & 4.2.0 it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You call to FirebaseDatabase when it is not initialized yet. Call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) in your Application class first.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Don't forget define your App class into Manifest file.

```
<application
        ...
        android:name="YOUR PATH TO App.class"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ...>
```

Comment: in which class should i call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context). I have 3 class namely main,login, and registration activity. If you dont mind please tell me how to define app class into manifest,since I'm new to android.

Comment: @Sunil create App class for example, how shown above, and add it to youк manifest file.

Comment: @Sunil show plz your App.class and manifest file 'application' block

Comment: I have updated both app class and manifest file in my previous answer. Please check it out